# MySQL Connection MAC to Windows 7

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, windows-7

I have my codes here and its working properly..
with Windows 7, but when I try to run my Java Program in MAC to Windows 7 as where my MySQL is, the program runs so slow.
But Mac to Mac its ok and no lag and also Windows 7 to Mac where my MySQL is.

```
package login;


import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class DatabaseCls {

public Connection con;
private void conData() {
    try {


       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.105:3306/eqod-log?user=root&password=3q0d.c0m");



    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public ResultSet rsFetch(String query) {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conData();
        rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        return rs;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ResultSet Query Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return rs;
    }
}

public boolean exSQL(String query) {
    boolean done;
    try {
        done = true;
        conData();
        con.createStatement().execute(query);
        con.close();
        return done;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        done = false;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Query Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return done;
    }
}
}
```

**Is there any settings where to change or speed up it, My database are save in Window 7**

```
"jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.105:3306/eqod-log?user=root&password=3q0d.c0m");
```

**and my program is installed in MAC computer, because the rest like (my program is on Windows 7 and my database Win 7) or (my program is on Windows 7 and my database is on MAC have no problems with lags or slow connection)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the my.ini in MySQL Settings
just type

skip-name-resolve
wait-timeout=15
connect_timeout=10

then save!

Answer (score 0):

The key is `when I try to run my Java Program in MAC to Windows 7 as where my MySQL is, the program runs so slow` Of course it is slower, because you are running over OS or over network. It will be always slower than the localhost!

Just check it: ru it on your windows 7 and put the mysql to other windows7 over the network: it will be slow.

Comment: No... I tried it Windows 7 to Windows 7 it works no slow connection

Comment: my program is only have slow connection if my database in on Windows 7 and my program is on MAC

Comment: Is there any settings where to change or speed up it, My database are save in Window 7

"jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.105:3306/eqod-log?user=root&password=3q0d.c0m");
and my program is installed in MAC computer, because the rest like (my program is on Windows 7 and my database Win 7) or (my program is on Windows 7 and my database is on MAC have no problems with lags or slow connection)

Comment: @kelvz there are firewall setings and other not programming related settings, which makes your code run slow. It isn't related to OS type the java slow running. It is almost the same speed on localhost if the settings are properly made at OS level and the hardware is the same.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL settings:-

```
skip-name-resolve wait-timeout=15 connect_timeout=10
```

and change string connection, add following line:-

```
&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
               + "&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10"
```

Comment: Please try to answer with detailed explanation, so that new user can understand what you are trying to convey.